# Using Cauchy Inequality for Simple Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $-\infty<\alpha<\beta<+\infty$ and $g\in C^1[\alpha,\beta]\setminus\{0\}$

How do I use the Cauchy inequality to show that if
$$
2|g(x)|\leq \parallel g' \parallel_{L^1(\alpha , \beta)}
$$
it holds that
$$
2|g(x)|\leq |\beta-\alpha|^{1/2}\parallel g' \parallel_{L^2(\alpha , \beta)}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $L^{2}$ function $h$ we have $(\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} |h|)^{2} =(\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} (1)(|h|))^{2} \leq \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} 1^{2} \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} |h|^{2}=(\beta-\alpha) \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} |h|^{2}$. Just take square root and put $h=g'$ in this.

Comment: Thank you, just a question: Why do we have $(\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} (1)(|h|))^{2} \leq \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} 1^{2} \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} |h|^{2}$?

Comment: That is  the Cauchy - Schwarz inequality.